# Issue While Saving Screenshot

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap

I am trying following code to capture screenshot:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as System.Drawing.Image);
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(25, 25, 25, 25, bitmap.Size);

    bitmap.Save("C:\\Users\\Mayank\\Desktop\\Screenshot\\", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

The last line is resulting into following error:
A generic error occurred in GDI+

Please help :)

Comment: bitmap.Save should get a file not a directory. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

```
int width=800;int height=480;
using (Bitmap bmpScreenCapture = new Bitmap(width,height))
{
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenCapture))
{
g.CopyFromScreen(0,0,0, 0,bmpScreenCapture.Size,CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);bmpScreenCapture.Save("test.png");
}
}
```

Comment: [Generic error in GDI+ occurs in Screen Capture](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15971438/3060520)

Answer (score -1):

Resolved this on my own. The problem was with the way I was providing the filepath and name. Resolved it with following code:

```
bmpScreenCapture.Save(@"C:\Users\Mayank\Desktop\Screenshot\TestFile.bmp");
```